# laravel-lighthouse get unknown argument error when use @spread

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

im using laravel-lighthouse package.

please look the method 2:

when i use `input and @spread` for my login mutation i will get some errors that you can see below:

[image]

but if i use method 1 it works without problem and return the token.
why?
(im using latest package.)

method: 1 (will return token. work correctly)

```
type Mutation {
  login(
    email: String!
    password: String!
  ): String @field(resolver: "AuthMutator@resolve")
}
```

method: 2 (return errors!)

```
input LoginInput {
    email: String!
    password: String!
}


type Mutation {
    login(input: LoginInput! @spread): String
        @field(resolver: "AuthMutator@resolve")

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shown in your screenshot is perfectly clear and tells you exactly what is wrong. `@spread` only changes how the arguments are received internally, but for a client the schema appears exactly as defined. In method 2, the field `login` expects a single argument `input`.